# <ul> overflow to next line in XHTML and CSS

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, xhtml

I have a list of items (`<ul>` containing `<li>`'s) which I want to limit by height.
Let's say I have the following code:

```
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
   <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

This will display as such:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
Item 6
```

I would like it to display like this:

```
Item 1       Item 4
Item 2       Item 5
Item 3       Item 6
```

Is there a way to achieve this without tables and without using different `<ul>` tags?

I'm looking for something like this - `<ul limit="3">` but I don't mind limiting it by height (i.e. `<ul limit="60px">`)

The reason I want this functionality is that I am generating the `<li>` tags dynamically.
I'm using Ruby on Rails - if this isn't possible with simply XHTML and CSS - is there a way to achieve this is Rails without literring the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer for the XHTML/CSS part: no, sadly, not yet. In the future, we will have [CSS columns](http://www.css3.info/preview/multi-column-layout/). Breaking it up into different lists is how I'm aware of this typically being done now.

**Update** There is this: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/ which gives a number of ways of doing it, but I'm not sold on them, especially for programmed output.

Comment: Ended up going with the CSS3 approach. This is for an admin system I know the users of will use Safari/Chrome/Firefox in their latest versions so it's not an issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh, sweet. I want your job. :) Ah well, back to debugging IE6.

Comment: lol! even google has decided to no longer support IE6. I just put a polite message on my personal sites that look like shit in those browsers that explains they will benefit from upgrading to a modern browser, and provide links. IE6 = vomit.

Answer (score 3):

Is the ordering a hard requirement?  If the width of the items is a known, you can do this:

```
<ul>
 <li>Item 1</li>
 <li>Item 2</li>
 <li>Item 3</li>
 <li>Item 4</li>
 <li>Item 5</li>
 <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul { width: 100px; }

li { width: 50px; display: block; float: left; }
```

That will render like this:

```
Item 1     Item 2
Item 3     Item 4
Item 5     Item 6
```

Comment: That's what I thought of too; if the order of the items isn't a requirement, that's a good approach. +1

Comment: I had that in mind when I wrote the question. The ordering does matter, though. Thank you for the response anyway!

Answer (score 1):

To get your array sorted in the correct order to use the floating  solution:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
a.partition{|el|el % 2 == 1}.flatten
a => [1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8]
```